# Manual column spacing in tabular environment and centering

Tags: tables

How can I adjust the column spacing in a tabular environment and also center the contents?

The code I use is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|p{8cm}|p{2cm}|}

\hline

1 & 2\\
\hline
3 & 4\\
\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Edit I:

Also while I was working in that code trying to create a second table under the first one both with the same width I ended up with the second being larger, although the width I gave was the same. Why is that happening?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|p{8cm}|p{2cm}|}

\hline

1 & 2\\
\hline
3 & 4\\
\hline

\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{4cm}|}

\hline
1 & 2 & 3\\
\hline
4 & 5 & 6\\
\hline


\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: there is tabcolsep padding either side of each cell, and arrayrulewidth of rule so the first table is10cm+4\tabcolsep+3\arrayrulewidth and the second is 10cm+6\tabcolsep+4\arrayrulewidth

Comment: use \centering\arraybackslash to center text

Comment: Thank you. How can I make them to have the same width without trial and error?

Comment: if you `\usepackage{calc}` you can use infix arithmetic so `p{3cm-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|` is a column of exactly 3cm including padding and the rule.

Comment: Also how do I use this command \centering\arraybackslash you mentioned earlier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can centre an individual entry (which is really just a `\parbox`) using

```
 1 &\centering 2 & 3\\
```

However `\centering` redefines `\\` so in the last column you need to use `\tabularnewline`

```
1 &\centering 2 &\centering 3\tabularnewline
```

Usually though you want to do this for a whole column so use the `array` package and then a column specification of

```
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}
```

applies centering and redefines `\\` to end a tabular row, in every entry in that column.

[image]

In the first table I centre a single entry `4` in teh second I centre all entries in the middle column. Both tables 10cm wide.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|p{8cm-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|
                 p{2cm-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}

\hline

1111 & 2222222\\
\hline
3 & \centering\arraybackslash 4\\
\hline

\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
                 >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
                 p{4cm-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}

\hline
111 & 2222 & 3333\\
\hline
4 & 5 & 6\\
\hline


\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't make the code to run. Where shall I place the code you have given me?

Comment: @Adam added some code and a picture